# include Association in Rails json Response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Academic Batch belongs to Academy

```
academic_batches = AcademicBatch.all
render json: {
  items: academic_batches.as_json({only: [:id, :name],include:[ academy: {only: [:name]} ]})                       
}
```

And the response looks like

```
[{"id"=>1, "name"=>"2010-2014", "academy"=>{"name"=>"College of Engineering Guindy"}}]
```

But for some other reason , i need the response as:

```
[{"id"=>1, "name"=>"2010-2014", "academy"=>"College of Engineering Guindy"}]
```

what changes should i make ??

Answer (score 0):

Define a method called `academy_name` and access like below,

```
academic_batches = AcademicBatch.all
render json: {
  items: academic_batches.includes(:academy).as_json({only: [:id, :name], methods: :academy_name})
}
```

It would be better if you use serializer(like https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers & https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi) for rendering JSON response. That makes the work simple

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
academic_batches = AcademicBatch.all
render json: {
  items: academic_batches.includes(:academy).as_json({only: [:id, :name]}).map {|a| a.merge(academy: a.academy.name)}
}
```